# Strategy for using Emacs as an event log?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

I'd like to be able to use Emacs to track various events in my day-to-day life, such as paying a bill, going to an appointment, replacing oil, etc. The goal would be to be able to view this event in two ways: one in which I see a timeline of all events (ie, I would be able to see that on Tuesday I had my dentist appointment and changed my oil); and another which would allow me to see all events of a category (changed my oil last Tuesday, 3 months ago ,...).

My first thought was to have an "events" org file dedicated to these entries, but it would be better to have them nested under the appropriate outline header, closer to relevant information. So ideally my outline would look like:

- Health

  - Dental

    - Address: 12123 asdfasdf

    [2018-02-03] Cavity filling

    [2018-10-03] Dental appt
- Car

  - License: a4fg920

    [2018-02-03] Purchased

    [2018-10-03] oil change

..and from that be able to generate a timeline for a certain heading or for all headings.

Is this within the scope of the agenda mode, or is there some "timeline" feature that I can use?